# Changing datatype to text in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

The original datatype is [h]:mm:ss

```
50:53:00
```

I want to change to text datatype like this

```
50h 53m
```

How to convert to this in excel-vba ?

Comment: like `Selection.Value = Application.Text(Selection.Value, "[h]""h"" mm""m""")`???

Comment: oh or as formula: `=TEXT(A1,"[h]""h"" mm""m""")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with or without vba.

1.Without vba

- Set the cells format to custom: [hh]"h" mm"m"

2.With vba

```
Sub numberf()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

ws.Range("F1").NumberFormat = "[hh]""h"" mm""m"""


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a UDF like this:

```
Function ConvertToText(TimeValue As Double) As String
    Hours = Int(TimeValue * 24)
    Minutes = Int((TimeValue * 24 - Hours) * 60)
    ConvertToText = Hours & "h " & Minutes & "m"
End Function
```

I'd put the original values in one column, use the formula in another one, and hide the original one if you don't want to display it.

Another option would be to give a Range to a Sub, link the sub to a button and have the sub walk through each cell in the range and do the changes.

Comment: the UDF is not functional . i use a string to store the output .The result generated is nothing (NULL).

Comment: You should declare `TimeValue` as a number format or at least use `cdate`... @vito pls check if that would help

Comment: my original `TimeValue` is in double format .Then , i directly input this into the function .

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this formatting of your excel cell below:

```
 h\h mm \m
```